# make a part of AJAX call dynamically

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a function which processes different kind of data.

For that it's necessary to add or remove

```
"processData: false,
 contentType: false,"
```

inside the ajax-call.

My first tries with an array of true/false, failed. How can I do that?

That's the call which I have to change dynamically

```
 $.ajax({
       //url: '".$global['serverurl']."module/".$m['ID']."/code/cms_data.php?job='+jobid+'&ds='+id+'&new='+jobnew+'&refreshid='+refreshid,
       url: '".$global['serverurl']."module/".$m['ID']."/code/cms_data.php',
       //type: 'PUT',
       type: 'POST',
       data: formData,
       processData: false,
       contentType: false,
       success: function(result) {...
```

If I try to work with a suggested function (@Lajos Arpad) like this

```
function getAJAXcall(processData, contentType, formData, callback) {
    var returnValue = {
       url: '".$global['serverurl']."module/".$m['ID']."/code/cms_data.php',
       type: 'POST',
       data: formData,
       success: callback
    };
    if (processData === true){ returnValue.processData = processData; }
    if (contentType === true){ returnValue.contentType = contentType; }
    return returnValue;
}
```

it won't work - if I code it by hand it will work, so I think in the function above is a little error?

```
function getAJAXcall(processData, contentType, formData, callback) {
    var returnValue = {
       url: '".$global['serverurl']."module/".$m['ID']."/code/cms_data.php',
       type: 'POST',
       data: formData,

       processData: false,
       contentType: false,

       success: callback
    };
    return returnValue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `function` to generate the object

```
function getAJAXObject(processData, contentType, formData, callback) {
    var returnValue = {
       url: '".$global['serverurl']."module/".$m['ID']."/code/cms_data.php',
       type: 'POST',
       data: formData,
       success: callback
    };
    if (processData === true) returnValue.processData = processData;
    if (contentType === true) returnValue.contentType = contentType;
    return returnValue;
}
```

and use it like this:

```
$.ajax(getAJAXObject(false, true, formData, function(result) {/*Something*/}));
```

Comment: can i set false/true by a variable? have i send in this case the formData to the function and how i have to make the callback functions in this case?

Comment: @newbieRB processData and contentType of the function are parameters, you can pass variables for them. The callback function is independent of the other parameters, you can pass any function for callback.

Comment: the hole text "processData....and contentType" should be remove or add - only with true/false it wont work correct for me

Comment: @newbieRB I have edited my answer, please check it out.

Comment: i get the error "formData is not defined" did i misunderstoud something?

Comment: @newbieRB no, you did not misunderstand it as far as I am not mistaken, however, apparently formData is out of scope in your case. I have added it as a parameter so you can pass it.

Comment: i'm sorry but please have a look at the main question, i've add some infos. Your function wont work in the right way.

Comment: @newbieRB in the function above we add processData and/or contentType as members to returnValue corresponding to the parameters if and only if the parameters are true. You are telling me it does not work. Can you also tell me how and with what parameter values did you call it, what did you expect and how did that fail?

Comment: see me answear above, in case to switch from === true, to === fase it will work, because true is the predefined function, if i want to change i need "fase"

Comment: @newbieRB I still do not understand how it does not work. Can you edit your question with the way you called this and information about what happened? You have an edit where you define them as false regardless of the values' parameters. That's incorrect, but I do not understand why did you change your code to that.

Answer (score 0):

based on the suggestion of Lajos Arpad

```
function getAJAXcall(processData, contentType, formData, callback) {
    var returnValue = {
       url: '".$global['serverurl']."module/".$m['ID']."/code/cms_data.php',
       type: 'POST',
       data: formData,
       success: callback
    };
    if (processData === false){ returnValue.processData = processData; }
    if (contentType === false){ returnValue.contentType = contentType; }
    return returnValue;
}
```

The important difference is the "=== false" not true.

True is standard, so it must add if it should be false!